# Why didn’t Fury ask for Captain Marvel’s help earlier?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel-2019

At the end of *Captain Marvel*, Carol gives Nick Fury a

> pager, upgraded to allow him to contact her across at least a couple of galaxies, for “emergencies only”.

She also leaves

> the Tesseract, from which her powers were derived,

on Earth with him. In the post-credits scene of *Avengers: Infinity War*, he uses

> the pager to contact Carol, presumably to ask for help with the small matter of loads of people dissolving out of existence.

However, weren’t there earlier occasions that called for the same action? Specifically:

> the theft of the Tesseract, and the subsequent use of it to allow an alien invasion of New York led by an Asgardian, in *The Avengers*?

Comment: Brie Larson and Samuel Jackson discuss it [here](https://www.instagram.com/p/Buy5Gk_FP7s)

Comment: @NikitaNeganov: the de-ageing CGI they put on Jackson in that Instagram video is amazing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Kevin Feige answered @ [**Slashfilm**](https://www.slashfilm.com/why-nick-fury-didnt-page-captain-marvel/)

> Peter: I have my nitpicky question I gotta ask you.
>
> Kevin Feige: I’m ready.
>
> Peter: And I know you probably have an answer for this. Why didn’t Nick Fury not use the pager until Infinity War? Because this big hole opened up in the sky and aliens attacked New York City.
>
> Kevin Feige: Well, I’d say two things. One, she does say it’s gotta be a real emergency, right? Yeah.
>
> Peter: Because that was just a city. I guess that’s not the world.
>
> Kevin Feige: The other thing I’d say is how do you know he never hit it? How do we know he never pushed it before? We’ve never seen him push it before. That doesn’t mean he never did.
>
> Peter: Good answer.

Samuel Jackson also chimed in

> And speaking with IGN, Samuel L. Jackson explained his view on why Fury hasn’t called Carol back to Earth yet:
>
> > **“We finally have an emergency that I feel warrants her presence**. This is unprecedented. How are you gonna fight that? I can’t fight that. If I’m not here, I need to find someone to come here who can handle it. All those people are ineffective. They’re great for normal, everyday world disaster. But intergalactic badass who has all the Infinity Stones needs a bit more.”

Comment: Plus that opens things up for a Capn Marvel sequel set between CM1 and Avengers 1

Comment: Fury had indeed already put his team together in *Avengers*, and believed in their ability to defend earth. He might have thought that a more solid bet than a partially-amnesiac test pilot who seemed fairly happy to stay up in the stars rather than hang around on earth.

Comment: And as Carol herself states, the pager does not have infinite range. Fury might have called her during *Avengers* only for her to be too far away to get the message.

Comment: @Valorum: the real continuity-porn sequel would show us why Carol didn't get involved when a member of her own race tried to destroy Xandar with an Infinity Stone.

Comment: Well she's Human, just with Kree blood. It was a Kree that tried to destroy Xandar and was defeated by a half-human. But yeah, it's weird that she wouldn't try to stop it.
As the end of CM shows, Ronan wants to capture Danvers, so perhaps CM2 will include her being captured and studied, and she's unable to intervene to protect Xandar. Perhaps being released when Ronan is defeated.

Comment: Probably she had no idea about the events in guardians of the Galaxy. Knowledge of the Infinity stone was restricted to Ronan and his cronies, the Collector and the Guardians. The time between the Guardians learning about the stone, Ronan getting it and then them defending Xandar isn't particularly long and so I doubt Carol Danvers would have even been aware of what was going on.